# Is there a way to have the touch bar set permanently on the function keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard, touch-bar

I know that, using the keyboard settings preference pane, you can set "touch bar shows" to "Expanded Control Strip" to remove the per-app buttons. This mirrors the out-of-the-box configuration on non-touchbar models where the physical F-keys would execute special functions (setting brightness, sound levels, etc), and holding down <kbd>fn</kbd> would let you use the normal <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> etc keys.

I'd like to set the opposite of this ([answered in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354459/can-i-lock-the-functions-on-the-touch-bar)) - where the bar *always* shows the F-keys, and requires holding down <kbd>fn</kbd> to access the special functions.

Is there a way to configure the touchbar in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard → Touch Bar shows ‘F1, F2, etc. Keys’.

[image]

Also set ‘Press fn key to Show Control Strip’ to use the Fn key to complete the inverting of the Touch Bar.